# Microsoft Azure Service Fabric SDK - Preview 1 fais to install on win 7 + VS 2015RC

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I am trying to install Azure Service Fabric SDK - Preview 1 according to [this MS article](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-get-started/) in which it is clearly stated that

> The tools for Service Fabric Preview 1 depend on Visual Studio 2015 RC, which you can find here.

I have VS 2015 RC PRO already installed. I have VS 2012 U4 too. Azure SDK 2.56 too.

The surprise comes when I try to download and install it. Here is a [screenshot of the error message](http://snag.gy/KxcJ4.jpg) - Windows Server 2012 is required.

[Here is log 1.](http://pastebin.com/9J0M3Nup)
[Here is log 2.](http://pastebin.com/Xtk9SWAq)

I just can figure out what is wrong and how am I supposed to develop for service fabric? Am I required to have WS 2012 with VS 2015 on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 7 is not supported for the preview. Supported OS versions are:

- Windows 8/8.1
- Windows Server 2012 R2
- Windows 10 Technical Preview

As Darran suggests, you can use the Azure VM gallery to get a Server 2012 image with VS 2015 RC pre-installed and then install the preview on top of it.

Feel free to add Windows 7 support as a request on the [Service Fabric UserVoice forum](http://feedback.azure.com/forums/293901-service-fabric).

Comment: It will be nice if MS sates all the prerequisites.

Comment: Yes, this will be fixed in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Which OS are you trying to install on? I believe Windows 8 / 8.1 are > Server 2012. I've got it running on Windows 8.1. You could always use a Server 2012 VM on Azure. There's an image in the MSDN gallery with VS15 RC pre-installed.

Comment: I am trying it on Win 7 Pro. There is nothing mentioned about windows 8 in the prerequisites in the article. But I see things like MSI (s) (68:94) [21:39:59:756]: APPCOMPAT: looking for appcompat database entry with ProductCode '{DA1CE6E8-B8CC-4748-B982-227D6703D97B}'.
MSI (s) (68:94) [21:39:59:756]: APPCOMPAT: no matching ProductCode found in database.
in the log file which smell a bit like that.